# Shifting an integer in JavaScript for storage?

Tags: javascript, numbers, bitmask

I've run into an issue that seems a bit weird and am wondering if anyone might be able to help with it.

I'm using JavaScript to store some integers via node.js and would like to use the full range of integers from `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` through `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` just calling negative zero a zero.

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp) it appears there are only 52 bits allowed (the first 52 bits), ignoring the sign, to retrieve `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` however it is clearly equal to `(2 ^ 53) - 1`.

The [ECMA spec](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5) on the otherhand says there are `(2 ^ 53) - 2` values (appearing to use `-0` as `NaN`.

I'm trying to pack integers into the smallest bitspace possible, 1-bit (1) sign, 1-bit (2) for null and the remaining bits for successively larger numbers.  This works great just adding more lines up until the last line of:

```
// sign is 0 for positive, 1 for negative and 2 for null
byte[0] = ((temp << 2) & 255) + sign;
byte[1] = (temp >> 6) & 255;
byte[2] = (temp >> 14) & 255;
byte[3] = (temp >> 22) & 255;
byte[4] = (temp >> 30) & 255;
byte[5] = (temp >> 38) & 255;
byte[6] = (temp >> 46) & 255; // produces a negative value prior to applying byte mask
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/voupa8u7/1/) with some relevant code incase it helps.

Comment: what exactly is your problem/question?

Comment: What you're attempting is likely to be impossible (or at least somewhat harder than it might seem), because not all possible arrangements of 64 bits in a double-precision value are valid numbers, and it's hard to know exactly what the CPU/runtime will do with those.

Comment: Actually I think I take that back; so long as you're careful with what bits you set/don't set, the low 52 bits at least should be fair game. Understand that the 11 bits of the exponent are "biased" by 1023, but otherwise I think any combination of bits there is also OK. Converting such "constructed" floating point values to strings and back again may or may not be reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IEEE floating point format has an implied leading `1` bit on the mantissa, but it's not actually present. In other words, all valid values have a leading 1 bit, so there's no point actually having it be explicitly stored.

You can look at [this jsfiddle I did the other day](https://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/nbmfy0gq/) to see how values are represented. Integers are represented as binary fractions multiplied by `2` raised to a power larger than `1`, except of course for the integer `1`, which has a mantissa of all zeros because of that leading implied `1` bit. (Actually every power of `2` is all-zeros in the mantissa.)

*edit* — for reference, the most sure-fire way I know to get directly at the bits in a floating-point value is to use typed arrays:

```
var f64 = new Float64Array(1);
var u8 = new Uint8Array(f64.buffer);
```

That gives you a one-element 64-bit array, and an 8 element unsigned 8-bit int array. Put a number in the `f64` array:

```
f64[0] = Math.sin(x); // or whatever
```

Then the `u8` array gives you the 8 bytes of that value, with the most significant byte (where the sign bit and exponent are) at `u8[7]`. IE versions less than 10 don't support typed arrays, nor does Opera Mini.

Comment: So is there a way to get the 7 bytes that represent `0` through `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`?

Comment: @CoryG Check that fiddle. Well tell you what I'll copy the key code into the answer.

Comment: Based in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/voupa8u7/3/) it appears that method exposes less of the underlying data.

Comment: @CoryG you're raising `2` to various powers. Because floating point is binary, you'll never see bits in your mantissa. You'll just see the exponent increasing. Try raising replacing `2` with `3` in your `Math.pow()` call.

Comment: Also your fiddle is writing out the bits backwards. [Here's a fixed version using `3` as the base.](https://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/pca7jog2/)

Comment: I'm a bit confused - shouldn't using 2 as a base be the method to see the progression of single active bits across the whole set in the example?  Why are there so many unused bits (the latter 80% or so) when using Math.pow(2, n) where n is 1-64?

Comment: @CoryG no, because it's floating point. The whole idea is that the value is represented by a mantissa and an exponent with an implied base. So the value of a floating point number is `mantissa * Math.pow(base, exponent)` - the implied base is `2`, so any power of `2` will have all zeros in the exponent because of that magic implied `1` bit that's assumed to be there at the start of the mantissa.

Comment: @CoryG Play with the fiddle I linked in my answer to see more.

Comment: I think I'm following now.  My next question though would be: is there a faster way to generate [this](https://jsfiddle.net/voupa8u7/5/) - ideally in 8-bit sections as numeric values or am I stuck having to parse the stringified number into byte values manually?

Comment: @CoryG well with the typed array trick you've basically got two views into exactly the same chunk of memory; it's like a union in C or C++. The `u8` values literally are the exact constituent bytes of the floating point value, and you can set them in the other direction: change an element of `u8` and the value of `f64[0]` will immediately reflect the change.

Comment: I'm understanding that part, but I'm trying to pack the `(2 ^ 53) - 1` valid integer values that can be contained in a floating point number into 7 bytes, shifted two bits off the base to add in a value for a null and sign flag, so 55 bits total or 7 bytes with a spare bit.  The `toString(2)` method looks like it could get me there with some additional processing but it seems like it is going to be horribly slow to go that route.

Comment: @CoryG it would be extremely helpful if you would extend your question to describe in much more detail exactly what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as correct because it had a fair amount of detail relating to the JavaScript floating point number type and how it functions internally and you deserve the reputation bonus for it.  If you have any ideas on handling bit length 33 - 53 without string parsing please check out [the rephrased post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34583357/1923100) - I've added a bounty on it as well because it is getting no responses.