# Fastest way to convert a integer to arbitrarily ordered byte arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, bitmask

I'm looking to convert the `MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` through `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` range of a JavaScript number (53-bits not including the sign) into a string of bits spread over 7 bytes shifted two to allow for sign and null identifiers.

Thus far the best I've come up with is:

```
function toUint8Array(data) {
    data = data.toString(2);
    data = new Array(65 - data.length).join('0') + data;
    var ret = new Uint8Array(data.length / 8);
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        ret[i] = 0;
        ret[i] += (data[i * 8] == '1' ? 128 : 0);
        ret[i] += (data[(i * 8) + 1] == '1' ? 64 : 0);
        ret[i] += (data[(i * 8) + 2] == '1' ? 32 : 0);
        ret[i] += (data[(i * 8) + 3] == '1' ? 16 : 0);
        ret[i] += (data[(i * 8) + 4] == '1' ? 8 : 0);
        ret[i] += (data[(i * 8) + 5] == '1' ? 4 : 0);
        ret[i] += (data[(i * 8) + 6] == '1' ? 2 : 0);
        ret[i] += (data[(i * 8) + 7] == '1' ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return (ret);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/voupa8u7/11/)

As you can tell right off, this would be abominably slow (and the bits still haven't been shifted two places across all 7 active bytes.)

Is there any way to do this faster?  Ideally by avoiding the string parsing altogether?

Comment: Actually DataView, **correctly used** i.e. not how you've attempted it, can give a modest (3X in Firefox, 1.5X in Chrome, **7.5X** in internet explorer) speed improvement - and I may be doing it sub-optimally

Comment: @JaromandaX I'd be curious to see how you are managing that to produce the output I'm attempting to get.

Comment: I can make a fiddle, but ... the input is strictly limited to MIN_SAFE_INTEGER -> MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - one question ... should the sign/null bits be the LSB of the 7th byte or the MSB of the first byte?

Comment: @JaromandaX the sign bit is the 1 place of the first byte and the null bit is the 2 place of the first byte [like in this fiddle that only goes to 32 bits](https://jsfiddle.net/voupa8u7/24/).  I'd actually be quite happy with the 53 bits allowed by `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` as I'm using `bignumber.js` beyond that, I'd just really like to avoid doing string parsing for bits `33` though `53` if possible.

Answer (score 5):

Bitwise ops in javascript are only 32 bits wide. But shifting is equivalent to multiplication or division by a power of two, and these happen with full floating-point precision.

So what you want to do is straightforward.  Shift to get the interesting part in the low-order bits, and mask off the rest.
E.g. you have a big number 0x123456789abc (20015998343868).

0x123456789abc / 0x1 = 0x123456789abc.  Bitwise AND with 0xff gives 0xbc.

0x123456789abc / 0x100 = 0x123456789a.bc.  Bitwise AND with 0xff gives 0x9a.

0x123456789abc / 0x10000 = 0x12345678.9abc.  Bitwise AND with 0xff gives 0x78.

And so on. Code:

```
function toUint8Array(d) {
    var arr = new Uint8Array(7);
    for (var i=0, j=1; i<7; i++, j *= 0x100) {
        arr[i] = (d / j) & 0xff;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

With a Uint8Array life is even easier: the masking with 0xff is implicit as Uint8Arrays can only store integers between 0 and 255.  But I've left it in for clarity, and so that the result will the same with different array types.

This code produces a little-endian array, e.g. 
`toUint8Array(0x123456789abc)` returns
`[0xbc,0x9a,0x78,0x56,0x34,0x12,0]`.
  If you want big-endian, i.e. the bytes in the opposite order, replace `arr[i]` with `arr[6-i]`.

(If you want the *bits* in each array entry in the opposite order this is slightly more complicated.  Replace `(d / j) & 0xff` with `bitrev((d / j) & 0xff)`, where bitrev looks something like this:

```
function bitrev(byte) {
   var table = [ 0b0000, 0b1000, 0b0100, 0b1100, 0b0010, 0b1010, 0b0110, 0b1110,
                 0b0001, 0b1001, 0b0101, 0b1101, 0b0011, 0b1011, 0b0111, 0b1111 ];
   return table[byte >> 4] + (table[byte & 0xf] << 4);
}
```

)

Finally, this only works on positive integers.  But your shifting-by-two idea is easily implemented.  `d*4` is d shifted left by two bits.  And `d < 0 ? -d : d` (or `Math.abs(d)`) is the absolute value of `d`.  So `arr = toUint8Array((d<0) ? 1-d*4 : d*4)` returns d shifted left by two bits, with the sign bit in the least significant bit (LSB).

And you can check for not-numbers with `isFinite()`, but you have to be careful to call it only on numbers, as `isFinite(null)`, say, is actually `true` due to implicit casting rules (this is fixed in ES6):

```
function toUint8Array_shifted_signed(d) {
   /* bit 0 is sign bit (0 for +ve); bit 1 is "not-a-number" */
   if (typeof d !== 'number' || !isFinite(d)) {
       d = 2; 
   } else {
       d = (d<0) ? 1-d*4 : d*4;
   }

   return toUint8Array(d);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is great - one additional question - is there a quick way to do the 2-bit shift while preserving all 53 original integer bits? If you do the `* 4` operation on a number greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER / 4` things can come out incorrectly.

Comment: * 4 is actually safe even for numbers greater than MAX_SAFE_INTEGER. Internally the mantissa is the same, the exponent is just incremented by two. MAX_SAFE_INTEGER doesn't mean that *no* integers above MAX_SAFE_INTEGER can be losslessly represented, only that there exist ones than cannot.
But while the code as it stands is correct for all positive integers, `1-d*4` can result in precision loss for large *negative* integers. There's also no check for overflow when d>=2^56, and no guarding against d not being an integer (where d*4 can leak the fractional part into the lower 2 bits).

Comment: I will update the answer for extra robustness in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

I hit the books, and a couple more math-side CS friends of mine, and our current verdict is that this can't be done as you're describing it.

I think you're stuck with the string-parsing.